# How can I FireEvent in callback from Firebreath

Tags: javascript, c++, callback, firebreath

I am a new to Firebreath. I have a task force to use a upload-file DLL through web page through Firebreath.
Now I have a callback problem.
There is a API in my dll.

```
int idu_initialize(transfer_callback pf);
```

callback funciton pointer define like this:

```
typedef void (*transfer_callback)(const char*)
```

transfer_callback is a upload process callback function.
I want html page can use transfer_callback to refresh html UI.
I do the following step:
method 1
define a PluginJsAPI function

```
registerMethod("fire_idum_initialize", make_method(this, &IDUMPluginAPI::fire_idum_initialize));
int fire_idum_initialize();
callback function like this:
void print_transfer_info(const char *s)
{
}
int IDUMPluginAPI::fire_idum_initialize()
{
    int result = idu_initialize(print_transfer_info);
    return result;
}
```

During  the file uploading process, the debug pointer can step into print_transfer_info callback
I define a js function in debug html

```
function load()
{
    addEvent(plugin(), 'upcb', function(msg){
          document.getElementById('callbackDiv').innerHTML=msg;});
}
```

i want to call fire_upcb(s) macro in print_transfer_info, but print_transfer_info is not IDUMPluginAPI member function, can not call fire_upcb(s)
how can i walk around it?
method 2:
define a js function callback, but how can i comsume the print_transfer_info callback?
how fire event to js from dll callback function print_transfer_info.
the print_transfer_info not a class member function;even if define print_transfer_info as a static class member function, cannot call fire_event,neither.
Any advises are very appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can you describe in higher level what you are aiming to do? Refresh UI when upload is proceeding?